# Running CRA Jest in non-interactive mode

Tags: reactjs, redux, jestjs, create-react-app

**Update: my use case is mainly to run tests at CI, but overriding default CRA Jest parameters is something I'm generally wondering about.**

---

I'm running tests using the [Jest](https://facebook.github.io/jest/), config that came with [Create React App](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app). It always launches into the interactive mode:

```
 › Press a to run all tests.
 › Press o to only run tests related to changed files.
 › Press p to filter by a filename regex pattern.
 › Press q to quit watch mode.
 › Press Enter to trigger a test run.
```

But I don't want it to wait for my input. I want it to run once and then terminate. I tried using the `--bail` or `--no-watchman` switches but it still launches in interactive mode.

If I globally install `jest`, and run it in the root of my project, it executes once and finish (just as I want). But when I run `npm test` which runs `react-scripts test`, it goes into the watch mode even when I'm not passing `--watch`.

Update: I've also filed an issue on [CRA](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/784).

Answer (score 216, accepted):

You should use [Jests `--watchAll=false` flag](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/cli#--watchall).

eg:

`npm test -- --watchAll=false`

**Note:** this is for [react-scripts > 3.00](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#remove---no-watch-flag)

*For older versions:*

- react-scripts `>= 2.1.4 < 3.00`

For non-ci, eg running tests locally, you can pass a `--no-watch` flag:

`npm test --no-watch`

- react-scripts `<= 2.1.3`

CRA looks for a `CI` environment variable, if its present it doesn't run in watch mode.

`CI=true npm test` should do what you are looking for

See the [User Guide -> Running Tests -> On your own environment](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/running-tests#on-your-own-environment)

Comment: yes, there's no easier way as far as this issue goes: https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/784

Comment: you can also do `react-scripts test --coverage`

Comment: This makes no difference for me on react-scripts 3.2.0; does not work.

Comment: looks like its --watchAll=false now

Comment: As one of the other answers already points out... it should actually be 
```npm test -- --watchAll=false```

Comment: I'm more of a vanilla webpack starter kind of guy, and when I started working an inherited react-scripts generated project, I was having trouble making the scripts start and stop automatically. This was killing my CI pipeline. This has been a tremendous help.

Comment: With react-scripts 3.4.3 it works when I remove `--`.  What is the purpose of this?

Answer (score 45):

In your `package.json` scripts:

`"test": "react-scripts test --watchAll=false"`

Or `npm test -- --watchAll=false`

Or `yarn test --watchAll=false`

Note: the flag used to be called `--no-watch` in `react-scripts < 3.0`: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/3.x/CHANGELOG.md#remove---no-watch-flag

Answer (score 3):

non-interactive solution:

```
npm test a --watchAll=false
```

or

```
yarn test a --watchAll=false
```