# Jest from create-react-app not running on Windows

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, babeljs, create-react-app, babel-jest

I have a problem running Jest from a clean installed app created using `create-react-app` on Windows 8.1. After the installation, running the command `npm run test`, I get the error:

`No tests found related to files changed since last commit.`

Running `jest --watchAll`, so bypassing the react-scripts, in the same directory, though, shows:

```
Test suite failed to run

Jest encountered an unexpected token

This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.

By default, if Jest sees a Babel config, it will use that to transform your files, ignoring "node_modules".

Here's what you can do:
 • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
 • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
 • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html

Details:

SyntaxError: E:\demo\src\App.test.js: Unexpected token (7:18)

  5 | it('renders without crashing', () => {
  6 |   const div = document.createElement('div');
> 7 |   ReactDOM.render(<App />, div);
    |                   ^
  8 |   ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(div);
  9 | });
```

Googling for quite while and following people's suggestions on similar issues, I started adding Babel devDependencies on my package.json. And it became like this:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.2.2",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.2.3",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.2.3",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/register": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.2.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "babel-jest": "^23.6.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
    "babel-plugin-root-import": "^6.1.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react-optimize": "^1.0.1",
    "jest-transform-stub": "^1.0.0"
  }
```

I also added the .babelrc file as:

```
{
    "presets": [
        "@babel/react" ,
        "@babel/env"
    ],
    "plugins": [
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"
    ]
 }
```

And no matter the combinations I try, I always get different errors and this can't be right. Looking at people on the internet, all are able to use the Jest command out of the box with create-react-app.

The last try with all those dependencies results in the following error:

```
Test suite failed to run

    E:\dev\demo\src\App.test.js:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){import React from 'react';
                                                                                                    ^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

      at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/script_transformer.js:403:17)
```

Any ideas?! I am baffled.

Comment: In case you have problems running tests with `npm test`, this is XY problem. A solution could be https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39724017/running-cra-jest-in-non-interactive-mode or possibly `npm test a`.

Comment: For the love of God, `npm test a` is the answer and it works fine. Thanks, @estus. If you want, add your solution as a normal answer, so I can mark it as the right answer.

Comment: I wasn't able to test it myself. Glad it works. Added it to the answer, hope this will help somebody else.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`create-react-app` is CLI that generates `react-scripts` pre-configured setup that includes Webpack and Jest configuration, among other things.

When Jest is used directly as `jest`, it ignores generated configuration and requires to be configured from scratch.

`npm test` (defaults to `react-scripts test` in CRA setup) should be used instead of `jest` to make use of generated Jest configuration.

In case the problem with  `npm test` is interactive mode:

> No tests found related to files changed since last commit. Press `a` to run all tests, or run Jest with `--watchAll`

It can be addressed with `npm test a`.

Comment: I've just installed CRA with the typescript template which has App.test.tsx out of the box but when I try your suggestion (pressing `a`) it just says `No tests found, exiting with code 0`.

Comment: @ThomasSoos The error is different, the one from the question means there are no new tests, while in your case no tests at all. As long as it's inside src/ I'd expect it to work. Possibly means that Jest is misconfigured out of the box. In case the problem persists and reproducible with up-to-date CRA, consider asking a new question regarding your case

Comment: Yes, it is under the src folder and I'd also expect it to work without any additional configuration. I'll ask around and if noone know I'll post a new question here. Thank you for your reply!

Comment: Just wanted to report back that I found what caused Jest not being able to find the unit tests. One of the project's parent folder had brackets ("[" and "]") in its name. As soon as I removed them Jest found the tests and ran them in a breeze ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @ThomasSoos Thanks for sharing, good to know. It's not uncommon for paths with special chars to cause problems though

Answer (score 6):

Just to clarify the answer of @estus-flask.
There are **2** solutions.

#### First Solution:

**`package.json`**

```json
"scripts": {
  "test": "react-scripts test --watchAll",
  ...
},
```

And then run

```bash
npm test
```

#### Second Solution:

**Or** when you run the tests, run them like this:

```bash
npm test .
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I am running a an Azure DevOps pipeline, to build and deploy a react  app to Azure app service. So I used the following script task to do npm install, npm build and then test as follows.

```
- script: |
    echo Working dir and file list are as follows.
    echo -----------------------------------------
    pwd
    ls -la
    echo Changing directory to reactonazure
    ehco ----------------------------------
    cd reactonazure
    echo Working dir and file list now after chaning directory are as follows.
    echo ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    pwd
    ls -la
    echo Running npm install
    echo -------------------
    npm install
    echo Running npm build --if-present
    echo ------------------------------
    npm run build --if-present
    echo Running CI=true npm test
    echo ------------------------             
    CI=true npm test
  displayName: 'npm install, build and test'
```

You can ignore echo, ls, pwd and cd statements. The point in focus it the last one

```
CI=true npm test
```

That finally started working. Earlier I had

```
npm run test --if-present
```

which gave me the error.

```
No tests found related to files changed since last commit.
```