# "No tests found" when running jest from command line

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, react-scripts

In a React project built with [`create-react-app`](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/) where the test files resides in the same folder next to the code they need to test, like follows:

```
|- /src/path
|  |- List.tsx
|  |- List.test.tsx
```

when trying to run `npx jest`, or using the global `jest`, I get the following result:

```
No tests found
In C:\src\path
  34 files checked.
  testMatch: **\*test.tsx,**/*test.tsx,src\**\*.test.tsx,src/**/*.test.tsx,C:\src\path\src\**\*.test.tsx,C:\src\path\src\**\*.test.tsx - 0 matches
  testPathIgnorePatterns: \\node_modules\\ - 34 matches
Pattern:  - 0 matches
```

Running `npm test` - which in turns run the script `react-scripts test` from `package.json` - works fine and is able to find and run all the tests in the project (in watch mode).

Any idea how to solve this problem?

#### Environment

- node: `10.15.0`
- npm: `6.4.1`
- react-scripts: `2.1.3`
- Operating system: `Windows 10 1809 17763.316`

#### jest.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  testMatch: [
    '**\\*test.tsx',
    '**/*test.tsx',
    'src\\**\\*.test.tsx',
    'src/**/*.test.tsx',
    '<rootDir>\\src\\**\\*.test.tsx',
    '<rootDir>/src/**/*.test.tsx',
    'src/.*|(.|/)(.test).tsx?$'
  ],
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54052883/334569), projects built with `create-react-app` are not meant to be tested directly with `jest`.

`react-scripts test` should be used instead of `jest` to make use of the Jest configuration generated by the CRA setup.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using `/` as a directory separator?

From [Jest docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#testmatch-array-string):

> See the micromatch package for details of the patterns you can specify.

From [Micromatch docs](https://github.com/micromatch/micromatch#backslashes):

> Micromatch exclusively and explicitly reserves backslashes for escaping characters in a glob pattern, even on windows. This is consistent with bash behavior.
>
> ...
>
> In other words, since `\\` is reserved as an escape character in globs, on windows `path.join('foo', '*')` would result in `foo\\*`, which tells micromatch to match `*` as a literal character. This is the same behavior as bash.

So I'd try:

```js
module.exports = {
  testMatch: [ '**/*.test.tsx' ]
};
```

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I have tried with `/` with no success. I have updated my questions with other patterns I have tried.

Comment: From here I can't really help because I'm not on windows... is `jest.config.js` in the same folder as `src`?

Comment: It is not in the same folder, it is one folder below it, in the root of the project.

Comment: @MarcoLackovic have you tried running without setting the matches? The [defaults](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#testmatch-array-string) seem to be fine for you.

Comment: same result with the default: `testMatch: **/__tests__/**/*.js?(x),**/?(*.)+(spec|test).js?(x) - 0 matches`

Comment: Then maybe raising a GitHub issue is the way to go if it doesn't work with the defaults.